# How to build a PHP rotator

Tags: php

I'm writing a script for a lead contact form that needs to send the first 10 leads to email 1, the second 10 leads to email 2, and so on until it gets to email 4, and then it goes back to email 1.

this is a rotator i have that was built for landing pages, but it rotates 1 each time rather than waiting 10 times, and then rotating. how would I modify this to suit my needs?

Also, it cant happen on every 'refresh' obviously. there would need to be a separate group of code which would go in the action="whatever.php" of the form and thats the code that would increment it.

```
<?php

//these are the email addresses to be rotated
$email_address[1] = 'email1@email.com';
$email_address[2] = 'email2@email.com';
$email_address[3] = 'email3@email.com';
$email_address[4] = 'email4@email.com';

//this is the text file, which will be stored in the same directory as this file, 
//count.txt needs to be CHMOD to 777, full privileges, to read and write to it.
$myFile = "count.txt";

//open the txt file
$fh = @fopen($myFile, 'r');
$email_number = @fread($fh, 5);
@fclose($fh);

//see which landing page is next in line to be shown.
if ($email_number >= count($email_address)) {
    $email_number = 1;
} else {
    $email_number = $email_number + 1;
}

//write to the txt file.
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $email_number . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

//include the landing page
echo $email_address[$email_number]; 

//terminate script
die();

?>
```

Comment: [Arrays in PHP are zero-indexed.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is there would be form to submit leads and when a lead is submitted, it has to follow your logic. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If that be the case,
use two a text file like track.txt. The initial contents of this text file would be 1,0. Which means leads are sent to first email id 0 times.

So in the action script of the form include the following code.

```
<?php
$email_address[1] = 'email1@email.com';
$email_address[2] = 'email2@email.com';
$email_address[3] = 'email3@email.com';
$email_address[4] = 'email4@email.com';

$myFile = "track.txt";

//open the txt file
$fh = @fopen($myFile, 'r');
$track = @fread($fh, 5);
@fclose($fh);

$track = explode(",",$track);
$email = $track[0];
$count = $track[1];

if($count >= 10)
{
  $count=0;
  if($email >= count($email_address))
  {
    $email = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    $email++;
  }
} 
else
{
  $count++;
}

$track = $email.",".$count;

//write to the txt file.
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $track);
fclose($fh);

//send lead to $email
```

?>